# ASP Chart YValueMember Missing Value after 9 Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Get Data from a WebServices and inserted into a DataTable (ds). All is perfect until the DataTable gets more than 9 rows. The YValueMember begin to Disappears. I set the SeriesCharType to Columns and also Bar and the results is the same, after 9 rows the label Name disappear either int Columns or Columns.

```
<asp:Chart  ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="900px" Height="600px" BorderSkin-SkinStyle="FrameTitle1" BorderSkin-BackColor="White">
            <Titles>
                <asp:Title></asp:Title>
            </Titles>
            <Series>
                <asp:Series  IsValueShownAsLabel="true"  IsVisibleInLegend="true" LabelForeColor="Black" LabelFormat="N2"  Color="#F7FE2E"  >
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <Series>
                <asp:Series IsValueShownAsLabel="true" IsVisibleInLegend="true" LabelForeColor="Black" LabelFormat="N2">
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>              
            <Series>
                <asp:Series IsValueShownAsLabel="true" IsVisibleInLegend="true" LabelForeColor="Black" LabelFormat="N2" Color="YellowGreen">
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <Legends>  
                <asp:Legend   
                    Name="Legend1"  
                    BackColor="White" 
                    ForeColor="Black"  
                    BorderColor="White" 
                    Docking="Bottom">  
                </asp:Legend>  
            </Legends>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
```

The C# Code is this:

```
            Chart1.DataSource = ds;

        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        Chart1.Series[0].IsXValueIndexed = true;
        Chart1.Series[0].Name = "Costo" + ": " + costo.ToString("N2");
        Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Name";
        Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "CostoTotal";

        Chart1.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        Chart1.Series[1].IsXValueIndexed = true;
        Chart1.Series[1].Name = "Venta" + ": " + venta.ToString("N2");
        Chart1.Series[1].XValueMember = "Name";
        Chart1.Series[1].YValueMembers = "VentaTotal";

        Chart1.Series[2].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        Chart1.Series[2].IsXValueIndexed = true;
        Chart1.Series[2].Name = "Utilidad" + ": " + utilidad.ToString("N2");
        Chart1.Series[2].XValueMember = "Name";
        Chart1.Series[2].YValueMembers = "Utilidad";

        Chart1.Series[0].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.Series[0].Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);

        Chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.Series[1].Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);

        label_valorizado.Text = " - Total: " + valoracion.ToString("N2");

        Chart1.Series[2].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.Series[2].Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);

        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.DataBind();
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
```